# Updating UI element when IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings are changed on another page

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am building a game for the Windows Phone using Silverlight for the GUI.

I have two pages in the game - MainPage and GamePage. MainPage contains CheckBox'es for game settings databound to a class which controls application settings (sound ? on : off, etc...)

```
<local:AppSettings x:Key="appSettings"></local:AppSettings>
```

...

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Sound" Content="CheckBox" Height="80" Margin="258,0,262,134" Style="     {StaticResource CheckBoxStyle2}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource appSettings}, Path=SoundEffectsSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

In the model, I use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to persist the settings.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Property to get and set a Sound Effects Setting key.
    /// </summary>
    public bool SoundEffectsSetting
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(SoundEffectsSettingKeyName, SoundEffectsSettingDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            AddOrUpdateValue(SoundEffectsSettingKeyName, value);
            Save();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sound");
        }
    }
```

Changing the setting in MainPage works fine. I can also turn the sound on or off in the GamePage. However, because the ViewModel creates its own "copy" (not sure of the correct term) of AppSettings in memory, when I turn the Sound setting "OFF" in the GamePage, it is not reflect in the MainPage when I navigate back. IsolatedStorageSettings is initialized in the constructor of AppSettings.

```
// Our isolated storage settings
    IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore;

/// <summary>
    /// Constructor that gets the application settings.
    /// </summary>
    public AppSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the settings for this application.
            isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I thought that I could just update the BindingExpression

```
Trajectory.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty).UpdateSource();
```

However, I figured out DUH! that is updating the model to reflect what's in the view. Which means that the SoundEffectsSetting value (in the model) is changed to the current state of the Sound checkbox (in the ViewModel).

So, what I did is this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!_Loaded)
        {
            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();

            if (appSettings.SoundEffectsSetting)
            {
                Sound.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Sound.IsChecked = false;
            }

            if (appSettings.TrajectorySetting)
            {
                Trajectory.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Trajectory.IsChecked = false;
            }

        }

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

_Loaded is switched in the OnNavigatedFrom method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {

        _Loaded = false;
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }
```

Now to my question. Can databinding be used to update Sound checkbox (on MainPage) when the sound setting is changed in GamePage? Or is my solution the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one global instance of `AppSettings` class created in `App Resources` or as a static field in `App` class that assigned to `DataContext` of both pages. In this situation all changes will propagate to target elements during `PropertyChanged` event.